How to cast a string/varchar 20240627181610100000 to timestamp(3/6) in Teradata?
Can you help me understand how the timestamp formats works with miliseconds in Teradata?
for-example this works fine
Value: 20240627181751
Format: YYYYMMDDHHMISS
SELECT CAST( '20240627181751' AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS')
but as soon I have miliseconds '20240627181751000' it starts failing tried different format like 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS.S(3)', I don't want to use sub-string functions.

try select to_timestamp( '20240627181610100000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF6').

SOrry, forgot to actually explain.  To cast  a string to a timestamp(6) using format, the milliseconds have to be separated with a .    This would work:  select cast('20240627181610.100000' as timestamp(6) FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS.S(6)').
